# how to test server REST API with testem

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, karma-runner, testem

Testem has a config option `serve_files` that serves the client side code for me. But i need to run my server because It has a `REST API`, and client side uses it.

How do i configure testem to run my server before running the tests? Or is this against the testem rules?

Because testem runs on another port and my rest api references to rest api won't work.
So i need to tell testem to bypass `serve_files` and launch my actual server and test the files from there.

**PS**: Or another alternative would be to stub the api with sinonjs or something, would that be a proper approach? Then i wouldn't really be testing my API with the ember generated templates using the API.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can say that I had the same issue 2 weeks ago. I ended up using a local storage adapter to save my data on the client, eliminating the need for the server. If that's an option for you, I think it's a better way to test your application.

Comment: @GJK you mean fixtures, i think real server is better way, that should be simple enough to do.

Comment: [`supertest` module](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) is the perfect tool for unit-testing REST API in node.js.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I will check it out, still I should mock the API or something.

Comment: Does the [API Proxy](https://github.com/airportyh/testem#api-proxy) option help?

Comment: O, M, G, I guess that is the answer @StephenThomas.

Comment: Then I guess I'll make it official.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [API Proxy](https://github.com/airportyh/testem#api-proxy) setting:

The proxy option allows you to transparently forward http requests to an external endpoint.

Simply add a proxies section to the testem.json configuration file.

`{
  "proxies": {
    "/api": {
      "port": 4200,
      "host": "localhost"
    },
    "/xmlapi": {
      "port": 8000,
      "host": "localhost"
    }
  }
}`

This functionality is implemented as a transparent proxy hence a request to `http://localhost:7357/api/posts.json` will be proxied to `http://localhost:4200/api/posts.json` without removing the /api prefix.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.